# Force execution of CMake install directive

Tags: c++, cmake, cmakelists-options

I have a CMakeLists.txt where I copy files in a specific order but the execution order seems random:

```
#First Installation
   install(DIRECTORY ${SIT_AW_FIRST_WORKSPACE_DIR}/ DESTINATION ${WS_DESTINATION_DIR})

#Second Installation that should overwrite a subset of files
   install(DIRECTORY ${SIT_AW_SECOND_WORKSPACE_DIR}/ DESTINATION ${WS_DESTINATION_DIR})


Output :


-- Installing: /opt/FOO/share/baz/xml/Login.xml

-- Up-to-date: /opt/FOO/share/baz/xml/Login.xml
```

The second file will not overwrite the first because they have the same timestamp and the same name, but they have different size. Is there a way to force the copy?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have better success by using the PATTERN and EXCLUDE options instead of trying to overwrite one file with another.  You could try something like this:

```
#First Installation
install(DIRECTORY ${SIT_AW_FIRST_WORKSPACE_DIR}/ DESTINATION ${WS_DESTINATION_DIR}
        PATTERN "Login.xml" EXCLUDE)

#Second Installation that should overwrite a subset of files
install(DIRECTORY ${SIT_AW_SECOND_WORKSPACE_DIR}/ DESTINATION ${WS_DESTINATION_DIR})
```

You can read the CMake docs here with the specifics here:  https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/command/install.html#installing-directories